# Web Scraping Nytimes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code:

```
url="https://www.nytimes.com/reuters/2018/04/05/business/05reuters-usa- 
tradechina-ip.html"
html = urlopen(url).read()    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

def text_from_html(body):
 texts = soup.find_all('p',class_="story-body-text story-content")
 return texts

print(text_from_html(html)[0])
```

My Output:
[image]

How can I print just the text and not the other information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(text_from_html(html)[0].text)
```

will do the work

Comment: good day dear radzak - great. I try to re-run this here. At the moment i struggle abit